# colorbox jquery broken https error

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am trying to use colorbox within an HTTPS-page.when I make the colorbox jquery link in https it is not working else it is working in http link.Does anybody have a solution for this problem?
 this link broken the colorbox working.

```
  https://markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSL certificate for the host only applies to ***www***.markettrendsignal.com, so you get an "Untrusted connection" alert when trying to get the file, when linked without "www."

This link works: https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they don't have a wildcard SSL certificate. Just change the link you're using to: `https://www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js`.

Also: for external resources, a nice trick is to use a **Protocol-Relative URL**, which looks like this:

`<script src="//www.markettrendsignal.com/beta/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js">`

Notice no `http` or `https`. Basically, what this will do is load the resource with whatever protocol is being used on the current page.